# IntelliJIdea 15.0.1 haven't play framework in scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I want create play project but plugin of intellij idea 15 can not support play framework . just has `scala` , `sbt`, `activator`.

Comment: are you using the ultimate edition? I believe only the paid version supports Play Framework.

Comment: i using community edition.

Answer (score 3):

Only the Ultimate edition of Intellij supports Play Framework.

If you check the [IntelliJ comparison page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) you will see that **Web Development** support (which includes Play) is greyed out if you switch to Community Edition.